# How to extract .zip files to a directory within a lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, async-await

The issue that I am running into is that when I test the function against a .zip file when the function gets to the fs.createReadStream&Zip the function is not running or returning an error and I would like to get an understanding on what I am doing wrong and how a correct solution would look.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    // Variables for bucket init
    let sourceBucket = 'am-doc-mgmt-s3-dev-landing';
    let storageBucket = 'am-doc-mgmt-s3-dev';

    // Variables for folder init and Buffer config
    const localZippedFolder = '/tmp/ZippedStudentData/';
    const localUnzippedFolder = '/tmp/UnzippedStudentData/';

    const ZipBuffer = Buffer.from(localZippedFolder, 'base64');
    const UnzippedBuffer = Buffer.from(localUnzippedFolder, 'base64');

    // Inits AWS s3 Bucket and DynamoDB
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

    // Gets the file bucket and file name of the s3 object from context
    let fileBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    let fileName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    let params = {
        Bucket: fileBucket,
        Key: fileName
    };

    // Creates temporary variables
    let tempFile = localZippedFolder + fileBucket;
    let tempUnzippedFile = localUnzippedFolder + fileBucket;

    // Make Directories for Zipped and Unzipped files
    try {
        const zipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localZippedFolder, { recursive: true })
        const unZipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localUnzippedFolder, { recursive: true });
        console.log('SUCCESS: unzipped directory created!');
        console.log('SUCCESS: zipped directory create!')

    // Download files from s3 Bucket
        let newFolder = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });

    // Extract files from zipped folder and store them in a local directory
       fs.createReadStream(params.Key)
        .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: unZipDirFolder}))
        .on('finish', () => {
             fs.readdir(unZipDirFolder);
        }).on('error', (err) => {
             // error handling here
             console.log(err);
    });

    }   
     catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

error: not getting anything back from the fs.createReadStream function. Its as if it just skips over the function.

Comment: So, your results would be where `fs.readdir(unZipDirFolder);` is.  You need to use the results INSIDE that event handler.  What are you expecting here?  The results are retrieved ascynchronously.  With this structure, the ONLY place you can use them is right where you do the `fs.readdir(unZipFolder)` (well that's async too so you'll have to do that appropriately too).

Comment: How are you expecting to call and use this `async` exported function?  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It skips over `fs.createReadStream().pipe()` because it's all asynchronous.  It finishes when you get the `finish` event.  Meanwhile, it keeps running other stuff.

Comment: Okay so to solve the problem I need to remove the fs.readdir() function from its current placement and return the results in its place?

Comment: No, it won't do you any good to return from inside an event handler.  That doesn't return from your main function.  See the promise wrapper I added below (same concept I showed you in your other question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's honestly hard to figure out what problem you're really trying to solve since you just aren't very specific about that.  If you want the containing `async` function to not resolve it's promise until the unzipping is done, you can wrap the stream in a promise like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    // Variables for bucket init
    let sourceBucket = 'am-doc-mgmt-s3-dev-landing';
    let storageBucket = 'am-doc-mgmt-s3-dev';

    // Variables for folder init and Buffer config
    const localZippedFolder = '/tmp/ZippedStudentData/';
    const localUnzippedFolder = '/tmp/UnzippedStudentData/';

    const ZipBuffer = Buffer.from(localZippedFolder, 'base64');
    const UnzippedBuffer = Buffer.from(localUnzippedFolder, 'base64');

    // Inits AWS s3 Bucket and DynamoDB
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

    // Gets the file bucket and file name of the s3 object from context
    let fileBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    let fileName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    let params = {
        Bucket: fileBucket,
        Key: fileName
    };

    // Creates temporary variables
    let tempFile = localZippedFolder + fileBucket;
    let tempUnzippedFile = localUnzippedFolder + fileBucket;

    // Make Directories for Zipped and Unzipped files
    try {
        const zipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localZippedFolder, { recursive: true })
        const unZipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localUnzippedFolder, { recursive: true });
        console.log('SUCCESS: unzipped directory created!');
        console.log('SUCCESS: zipped directory create!')

        // Download files from s3 Bucket
        let newFolder = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Extract files from zipped folder and store them in a local directory
           fs.createReadStream(params.Key)
                .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: unZipDirFolder}))
                .on('finish', resolve);
                .on('error', reject);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // rethrow error so caller sees the error
        throw error;
    }
};
```

And, your caller using this exported function will HAVE to use `.then()` or `await` on the returned promise to know when it's done.  And, use `.catch()` or `try/catch` around `await` to catch errors.

Comment: okay well my goal is to unzip the file and be able to see a log of the unzipped files in a directory. upon running the code this is the error that was returned

2020-03-04 21:14:11.459 {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Jerry-user-data.zip'"

Comment: @brycent - And, where did that message occur?  That would probably NOT be in this code.  We really can't help you very productively until you show the ENTIRE code path  from start to finish and show what error you got and where you got that error and describe what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @brycent - This exported function is asynchronous.  It returns a promise.  The caller of this function (with the code I've added to it) has to USE that promise to know when it's done before trying to read the unzipped files.

Comment: the error message i received occurred when the code got to the await new promise function, then the lambda timed out. It could have something to do with the amount of time elapsed in terms of how long it takes to unzip the file

Comment: i think its the way I am creating the temp directory that is throwing the error, that is why when it gets to the function it could be breaking it

Answer (score 0):

If someone's open to using Python, they can use a buffer to read and unzip the files. Something like this:

```
        zipped_file = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=sourcebucketname, key=filekey)
        buffer = BytesIO(zipped_file.get()["Body"].read())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
        
        for file in zipped.namelist():
            logger.info(f'current file in zipfile: {file}')
            final_file_path = file + '.extension'

            with zipped.open(file, "r") as f_in:
                content = f_in.read()
                destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's also a tutorial here: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9